# Docker container autostart, starts only after `container ls`

Tags: docker

I have created a container with parameter `restart=always` on the run command.
But after a reboot, my container start automatically only after I do a `container ls -a` !
It's not really automatically...

Have you an idea why ?
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details about what you want to achieve, what you have tried and what goes wrong. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It sounds like you have docker configured not to start automatically, but rather to start when something attempts to connect to the docker socket. If the output of `systemctl is-enabled docker` is `disabled`, try running `systemctl enable docker` and rebooting and see if that does it (both commands must be run as `root`).